# Filling a form using Ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to find out how to fill a form from https://www.otodom.pl/ using Ruby mechanize gem, but it doesn't work. I've tried some variants and recommended solutions, but still nothing. Problem is, that when I submit a form (I need to fill first field by value = "Wrocław"), it goes next, but next page is a result of submission of empty form. Why? How to set this field correctly and after submission goes to correct page?

Regards!

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
main_page = agent.get 'https://www.otodom.pl/'

form = main_page.form(:class => "form form-search")

form.field_with(:name=>"search[LOCATION]").value = "Wrocław"
form.fields.each{|f|
  puts f.name
  puts f.value
}

sec_page = form.submit

puts sec_page.uri.to_s

rows = sec_page.root.css(".col-md-content article")

rows.take(10).each do |row|
  title = row.at_css(".text-nowrap span").text.strip
  puts "#{title}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the page, and as far as I can tell, there is no `input` named `search[LOCATION]`. Furthermore, the form values seem to be numerical identifiers, such as `search[city_id]=39` when the field shows  Wrocław, dolnośląskie, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: input fields]

Comment: I try to do it many ways. I see, that there is no 'search[LOCATION]', but when I print out field names belongs to this form it gives me: search[LOCATION], search[dist], search[category_id]
I tried to fill fields like search[city_id], but it only returns me an error (there is no field like that). Maybe there is a better library than Mechanize or maybe I didn't find a proper method in its documentation?